# Prisma MongoDB: Cannot connect to 'Post' collection while 'User' collection works fine

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm building a Next.js 13 application with Prisma as the ORM and MongoDB as the database. I have defined two models in my Prisma schema, namely 'User' and 'Post'. The 'User' model works perfectly fine, but I'm facing an issue with the 'Post' model.

Here is my Prisma schema:

```
// prisma/schema.prisma

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  // ... (other fields)
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  content   String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  author    User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  userId    String
}
```

The problem:
I can successfully connect to the 'User' collection and perform operations on it using Prisma, but I'm unable to connect to the 'Post' collection. When I attempt to create, read, or update data in the 'Post' collection, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: Could not find mapping for model Post
    at gn.createMessage (C:\Users\myName\OneDrive\Desktop\Next\blog\blog-post\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:164:772)
    // ... (other stack trace lines)
```

I've double-checked the schema and database configurations, and they seem correct. I've also ensured that my Prisma Client is up-to-date (4.16.1) and the MongoDB database is running and accessible.

Here's an example of the code that throws the error:

```
// API code to create a new post
import prisma from '../../libs/prismadb'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function POST(request) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const { content, userId } = body;

  if (!content || !userId) {
    return new NextResponse('Missing Fields', { status: 400 })
  }

  const post = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      content,
      userId,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(post);
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, and I've run out of ideas on how to debug it further. I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem. Thank you!

Environment:

```
Prisma Client version: 4.16.1
MongoDB version: (e.g., 4.4.9)
Node.js version: (e.g., 14.17.5)
Operating System: (e.g., Windows 10)
```

I expected that calling the `POST` API with valid `content` and `userId` would create a new post in the 'Post' collection of my MongoDB database. The new post should have the provided `content` and be associated with the user specified by the `userId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Could not find mapping for model Post
```

This error could be to due to the database not being synced with the schema. Did you `migrate` your changes after updating your schema and re-generating the Prisma client?

If not, try the following

```bash
prisma db push
```

`db push` is like running `migrate dev` but Prisma doesn't create any migration files for it. This is really useful for testing changes to your schema on the fly. It will also run `prisma generate` for you as well. Docs for `db push` are [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push).

Also make sure to create a migration before pushing your code for review:

```bash
prisma migrate dev --name your_migration_name_here
```

Hope this helps!